# What's the .apply jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, apply

I see that in different plugins and codes, but I don't understand what does that function... In the jQuery api isn't referenced!

Comment: It's not in the jQuery reference, since it's a [ **native Javascript function** ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Answer (score 128, accepted):

`apply` calls a function with a set of arguments. It's not part of jQuery, it's part of core Javascript. However, there is mention of it in the jQuery docs:

http://docs.jquery.com/Types#Context.2C_Call_and_Apply

Syntax:

```
somefunction.apply(thisObj, [argsArray])
```

The above calls the function `somefunction`, setting `this` to `thisObj` within the function's scope, and passing in the arguments from `argsArray` as the arguments to the function.

Comment: Related is the [ **.call() function** ](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) that also takes a `this`, but it is followed by a series of individually listed arguments instead of an array containing the arguments.

Comment: what will below do than? $.when.apply(null, object).done(callback);

Comment: @user1531437 That calls `$.when(object).done(callback);`, but in the function `$.when`, `this` is set to the first parameter, i.e. `null`. Arguably, one should be using `$.when.call(null, object).done(callback);` because the second parameter of `.apply` is supposed to be an array

Comment: Distantly related was the [jQuery proxy function](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/), which is useful to change the value of `this` i.e. the context variable, the way Javascript's native `apply` can do

Answer (score 5):

Essentially, apply will call a function with the context being set to the object you apply the function to. This means that within the function, referencing `this` will refer to that object.

Comment: For anyone working with jQuery and arriving at this answer, you'll need to use `$(this)` to get the associated jQuery object and have access to jQuery methods.

Comment: @R.Schreurs also you need to use the jQuery.fn object as seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27374435/674033