# jquery widget apply(this, arguments)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-widgets

Sometimes I see people using this to call function within a widget

```
this.myFunction.apply(this, arguments);
```

instead of this:

```
this.myFunction();
```

> [What's the .apply jQuery function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796788/whats-the-apply-jquery-function)
>
> ```
> somefunction.apply(thisobj, argsarray)
> ```
>
> *The above calls the function somefunction, setting this to thisobj within the function's scope, and passing in the arguments from
>   argsarray as the arguments to the function.*

But considering the case below, wouldn't it be the same whether calling the function directly or using .apply()? I've seen a few tutorials favor .apply() method instead, including the jQuery site itself. http://jqueryui.com/demos/widget/

Is this a widget 'standard' or is there something else that i'm missing?

```
_create: function() {
            var that = this;
            this.myButton = $( "<button>", {
                text: "My Button"
            })
            .appendTo( this.element )
            .bind("click", function() {
                // _bind would handle this check
                if (that.options.disabled) {
                    return;
                }
                that.displayMessage.apply(that, arguments);
                // Why not just call the following?
                // that.displayMessage();
            });
        },
displayMessage: function() {
        alert("Hey!");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not jQuery, it's JavaScript.  `.apply()` and `.call()` allow you to change what `this` means inside the function.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. What I'm asking is, why would one uses .apply() to call the widget function when they can just do this.myFunction()

Comment: Because JavaScript's 'this' is the thing that called it, not the object itself.  The technique is very useful for shimming 'this' from an unknown state -- likely a button that was clicked -- to be myself.  It's also useful if you want to grab all parameters passed to the current function -- perhaps an unknown quantity, and also pass other parameters too.

Comment: In your example, displayMessage() doesn't need a specific 'this', so just calling it is fine.  But what if displayMessage() called another function in the class like formatStyle().  If you called that.displayMessage(), it would call this.formatStyle() and fail because 'this' would be myButton.

Comment: Your answer did not answer my question. But your comment did. Thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

The `apply` method does a little more than allow you to specify the context for a function, it also allows you to supply the arguments as an array. From the [fine manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

> Calls a function with a given `this` value and `arguments` provided as an array.

The *`arguments` provided as an array* is important. The current arguments that a function was called with are available in the [array-like `arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) and the actual arguments are independent of the function's signature; for example, `f = function() {...}` can be called as `f(1,2,3)` and `f` can pull those three values out of its `arguments` if it wants.

So this:

```
that.displayMessage.apply(that, arguments);
```

calls `that.displayMessage` with the same arguments that `_create`  was called with without `_create` needing to know (or care) what parameters it was called with; this allows a function to slip itself in the middle of the call chain without having to muck about with possibly different numbers of parameters. This is quite different than just calling `that.displayMessage()`.

If the `_create` was called like this:

```
o._create('where is', 'pancakes house?');
```

then the `apply` call is equivalent to:

```
that.displayMessage('where is', 'pancakes house?');
```

but if different parameters were used:

```
o._create(1, 2, 3);
```

then the `apply` would act as though we did this:

```
that.displayMessage(1, 2, 3);
```