# JavaScript- this value

Tags: javascript, this

I see some [code like this from jqplot library](https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/src/e8af8a37f0f14ea1e8c630ecfe6f1b1933794036/src/plugins/jqplot.dragable.js?at=default#cl-37):

```
$.jqplot.Dragable = function(options) {
    // a bunch of code here.
    $.extend(true, this, options);
};
```

This is a routine to add new plugin to the library.

What does `this` refer to here in `$.extend(true, this, options)`? Is it the function itself or window, or it will only be specified when called?

Thanks!

**Update:**

This question was meant to be a general one because I don't understand `this` value in js. After some research, apparently: 
1. If called using func(), then `this` will be `window` or `undefined` (strict mode)
2. If called like foo.funct(), `this` refers to foo.

As for this specific jqplot library, when it's called it's actually called on `$.jqplot`, where jqplot was added to jquery. So `this` should refer to `$.jqplot`

Comment: here it looks like an instance of `Dragable`

Comment: Whatever the jqplot library chooses to set it to before calling extension functions. It's not necessarily anything automatic in JS.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I'm very new to js oop... Are you saying that Dragable is a constructor? Why? Or are all functions in js can be constructor?

Comment: @Barmar If it's called like this $.jqplot.Dragable(optionObj), then this == $.jqplot.Dragable?

Comment: You can try `console.log(this)`, it should tell you what it is...

Comment: Given the way it's being used with `$.extend`, it looks like `this` is an object containing the options for the `jqplot` instance.

Comment: @CharlesW. if you call it like `$.jqplot.Dragable(optionObj)` then `this` will be global object ie window

Comment: That's probably not how you call it, though. It's probably something like `$("selector").jqplot.Dragable(optionObj)`.

Comment: @CharlesW It depends on how you call it. If you call it like `$.jqplot.Dragable(optionObj)` then `this === $.jqplot`.

Comment: Also, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832062/the-scope-of-this/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example `$.jqplot.Dragable` is a constructor. `this` refers to the object created when

```
new $.jqplot.Dragable(options)
```

is called. As for `$.extend`, It simply copies every method and property from `options` onto `this`.

But nevermind that. First you should understand what `this` is. After that you can read the links I've posted at the bottom of my aswer to learn about constructors and OOP in JavaScript.

In javascript `this` refers to the context of a method or function. The value of `this` can be of three things.

#### Global Context

When simply executing a function by name or by a direct variable reference (not an object property), `this` points to the global scope. In the browser this is the `window` object.

*Note that in strict mode `this` is `undefined`*

```
function setFoo(val) {
    this.foo = val;
}
```

Above we have a function `setFoo`. This function simply takes a value and sets it on `this`. Lets execute the function to find out what will happen...

```
setFoo(10);
```

In this case, `this` refers to the global scope. For this reason, `window.foo` or `foo` should equal 10.

```
window.foo == 10 //true
foo == 10 //true
```

#### Object Context

When a function is stored as a property of an object it is called a method. When a method is executed `this` becomes the object the method is attached to. This allows the method to modify and use data on the object.

Now lets take setFoo and attach it to an object.

```
var myObject = {};
myObject.setFoo = setFoo;
```

If we execute with now myObject will have a new property called foo and it will equal what ever we pass into `myObject.setFoo`.

```
myObject.setFoo(34);
```

As it should `myObject.foo` equals 34 because `this` refers to the object `myObject`.

```
myObject.foo == 34; //true
```

#### Call Context

The last way `this` can be set is with to methods of the `Function` prototype. This means that all functions and methods in JavaScript have these to methods. They are `call` and `apply`. These functions allow the programmer to set a custom context while executing a function or method. The two are nearly identical except that apply takes an array as its second argument. Each item in the array is passed to the function/method as an argument in order.

call

```
var x = {};
setFoo.call(x, 20);
x.foo == 20; // true
```

apply

```
var x = {};
var args = [20];
setFoo.apply(x, args);
x.foo == 20; // true
```

You should read the article for `this` on MDN. It will help you better understand when to use this, and why its an important part of function scope.

[**MDN - this**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

You should also read because the main purpose of `this` is to enable OOP (Object Orientated Programming) in JavaScript.

[**MDN - Inheritance and the prototype chain**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. :) 
In strict mode, isn't it `undefined`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this