# Why does the value of "this" changes.?

Tags: javascript, this

I am learning javascript and i came across a doubt. Why is the value of "this" undefined in the first example , but prints out correctly in the second.

example 1:

```
var myNamespace = {
    myObject: {
        sayHello: function() {
            console.log( "name is " + this.myName );
        },
        myName: "john"
    }
};

var hello = myNamespace.myObject.sayHello;

hello(); // "name is undefined"
```

example 2:

```
var myNamespace = {
    myObject: {
        sayHello: function() {
            console.log( "Hi! My name is " + this.myName );
        },
        myName: "Rebecca"
    }
};

var obj = myNamespace.myObject;

obj.sayHello();//"Hi! My name is Rebecca"
```

Why does the value of "this" changes within the function. What concept am i missing?

Comment: That's how `this` works.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Your expectation is just fine, JavaScript's `this` semantic is broken. :-)

Comment: it is javascript not "java script".. very very great difference.. :)

Comment: @Waldheinz JavaScript `this` is more closely akin to the "receiver" concept in languages like SmallTalk than it is like the `this` concept in C++, Java, and/or C#.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832062/the-scope-of-this

Comment: Basically, the problem is that in Javascript, `this` is not bound when you access the method in the object (as in, say, Python), but only when you call it. So it's literally "the object to the left of the `.` in the actual method call expression." In your second example, that's `obj`, in your first example you don't call the method using the dot syntax so it's nothing. (And you can also choose what the value of `this` will be by using `Function.bind()` or when using `Function.call()` and `Function.apply()`, just to make things more complicated. jQuery does this pervasively.)

Comment: 1 example, hello is the function, 2 example hello is object myObject; function sayHello has no myName defined, while myObject has

Comment: See my related answer here for a complete explanation of how "this" works in javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628#13441628

Comment: I just answered one of your question, and you deleted it without even a comment. I find this of very bad taste.

Comment: @millimoose - I don't know if it's 100% technically accurate but I find your "object to the left of the `.` in actual call" metaphor way easier to understand than every other explanation I've ever read. You should consider making it a proper answer so it gains more visibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First case you are just getting the reference of the function to the vairable `hello`, and invoking it from global context (window in browsers, global in node), So `this` becomes what invoked the function except for (bound functions). You can always set the context explicitly using  [function.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or set the context explicitly to the function using Ecma5 [function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
hello.call(myNamespace.myObject); //now you are setting the context explicitly during the function call.
```

or just bind it while getting the function reference.

```
var hello = myNamespace.myObject.sayHello.bind(myNamespace.myObject); //Now no matter where you call it from `this` will point to the context of myObject
```

Second case you are invoking it from the object itself so `this` points to the object.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, the implicit `this` object is the global scope.  Because there is no `myName` in the global scope, you get undefined.

If you want a free function with the proper `this`, use `bind`:

```
var hello = myNamespace.myObject.sayHello.bind(myNamespace.myObject);
```