# Javascript/Typescript 'this' scope

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am working with Ionic2 and Meteor. I do however have a Javascript/Typescript issue relating to the scope of the `this` object.

I have [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19277395/why-does-the-value-of-this-changes) that I should use `bind` when I don't have handle on `this` at the appropriate level.

I probably don't understand the concept, because I try the following, but get an error trying to call a function.

```
this.subscribe('messages', this.activeChat._id, this.senderId, () => {
    this.autorun(() => {
        let promiseMessages: Promise<Mongo.Collection<Message>> = this.findMessages();
        promiseMessages.then((messageData: Mongo.Collection<Message>) => {
        messageData.find().forEach(function (message: Message) {
            setLocalMessage.bind(message);
        });
    });
});
```

and

```
private setLocalMessage(message: Message): void {
   this.localMessageCollection.insert(message);
}
```

I get the following error when I try build the app:

> ```
> ERROR in ./app/pages/messages/messages.ts
> (72,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'setLocalMessage'.
> ```

**UPDATE**

Thank you for the advise below.

I am now using the following, and it works.

```
          let promiseMessages: Promise<Mongo.Collection<Message>> = this.findMessages();
          promiseMessages.then((messageData: Mongo.Collection<Message>) => {
            messageData.find().forEach((message: Message) => {
              this.setLocalMessage(message);
            });
          });
```

Comment: It might be a typo, but your function is declared setLocal**Message** and your error says setLocal**Nessage** - is this a typo or the actual problem?

Comment: It might also be worth adding the "typescript" tag (maybe even instead of the "javascript" tag), as this is typescript code.

Comment: Sorry, was a typo, fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have read that I should use `bind` when I don't have handle on this at the appropriate level.

That's a bit outdated now, better have a look at [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572) these days which also shows you how to use arrow functions.

You're getting the error message because `setLocalMessage` is not a variable but still a property of `this` so you have to access it as such. There are basically three solutions in your case:

- `bind`

  ```
  messageData.find().forEach(this.setLocalMessage.bind(this));
  ```
- the context argument of `forEach` (assuming it's the `Array` method):

  ```
  messageData.find().forEach(this.setLocalMessage, this);
  ```
- another arrow function:

  ```
  messageData.find().forEach((message: Message) => {
      this.setLocalMessage(message);
  });
  ```

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try

Comment: Thanks Bergi, that worked, it now calls that function.  However, I am now having an issue that something in that function doesn't work. Would you mind looking at the following please?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39854896/typscript-not-inserting-into-mongo-collection

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong here.

In ES6 (and thus TypeScript), you need to refer to instance members using explicit this, such as `this.setLocalMessage`. Just writing `setLocalMessage` is invalid no matter where the code is.

Inside a `function`, the `this` object will probably not be what you expect anyway. You need to capture the `this` object from outside the function and put it in a variable, like so:

```
this.subscribe('messages', this.activeChat._id, this.senderId, () => {
    this.autorun(() => {
        let self = this;
        let promiseMessages: Promise<Mongo.Collection<Message>> = this.findMessages();
        promiseMessages.then((messageData: Mongo.Collection<Message>) => {
        messageData.find().forEach(function (message: Message) {
            self.setLocalMessage(message);
        });
    });
});
```

Alternatively, you can use an arrow expression, in which `this` is the same as what it is in the code around it:

```
this.subscribe('messages', this.activeChat._id, this.senderId, () => {
    this.autorun(() => {
        let promiseMessages: Promise<Mongo.Collection<Message>> = this.findMessages();
        promiseMessages.then((messageData: Mongo.Collection<Message>) => {
        messageData.find().forEach(message => this.setLocalMessage(message));
        });
    });
});
```

It's not an issue of TypeScript itself. Without it, the code will just fail at runtime.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try

Comment: Thanks Greg, that worked, it now calls that function.  However, I am now having an issue that something in that function doesn't work. Would you mind looking at the following please?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39854896/typscript-not-inserting-into-mongo-collection