# Typescript not inserting into Mongo Collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor, typescript

I am using Ionic2 with Meteor/MongoDb.

I have a `collection`, that I am trying to `insert` a `message` object into. However, the code seems to freeze where it tries to do the `insert`.  However, if I try insert the `message` object from a different place (i.e. invoke `setLocalMessage(message: Message)`), it does so successfully. This makes me think, the problem is not with the `collection` or `message` objects, but rather the way I am calling the function that does the insert.

```
private localMessageCollection: Mongo.Collection<Message> = new Mongo.Collection<Message>(null);
```

and

```
  private loadMessages(): void {
    let promise: Promise<string> = this.utilityService.getLoggedInPerson();
    if (promise) {
      promise.then((data) => {
        this.personModelLoggedIn = JSON.parse(data);
        if (this.personModelLoggedIn) {
          this.senderId = 'P' + this.personModelLoggedIn.id;
          this.title = this.activeChat.title;
          this.picture = this.activeChat.picture;
          this.subscribe('messages', this.activeChat._id, this.senderId, () => {
            this.autorun(() => {
              let promiseLocalMessages: Promise<Mongo.Collection<Message>> = this.findLocalMessages();
              promiseLocalMessages.then((messageData: Mongo.Collection<Message>) => {
                messageData.find().forEach((message: Message) => {
                  this.setLocalMessage(message);
                });
              });
              let promiseMessages: Promise<Mongo.Collection<Message>> = this.findMessages();
              promiseMessages.then((messageData: Mongo.Collection<Message>) => {
                messageData.find().forEach((message: Message) => {
                  this.setLocalMessage(message);
                });
              });
            });
          });
        } else {
          this.nav.push(LoginPage, {
            fromMessages: true
          });
        }
      });
    } else {
      this.nav.push(LoginPage, {
        fromMessages: true
      });
    }
  }
```

and

```
  private setLocalMessage(message: Message): void {
    console.log('setLocalNessage: ' + message._id);
    console.log(this.localMessageCollection);
    this.localMessageCollection.insert(message);
    console.log('setLocalNessage done: ' + message);
  }
```

output

> ```
> setLocalNessage: eC7hDZ4Z6ZwTnjP4h 
> Mongo.Collection {_makeNewID: function, _transform: null, _connection: null, _collection: LocalCollection, _name: null…}
> ```

but then it freezes.

If anyone can assist I would appreciate it.

**UPDATE**

It is freezing in the Meteor api on this line:

```
}Meteor.default_connection=Meteor.connection;Meteor.connect=DDP.connect}).call(this);if(typeof Package==="undefined")Package={};(function(pkg,symbols){for(var s in symbols)s in pkg||(pkg[s]=symbols[s])})(Package["ddp-client"]={},{DDP:DDP,LivedataTest:LivedataTest})})();(function(){var Meteor=Package.meteor.Meteor;var global=Package.meteor.global;var meteorEnv=Package.meteor.meteorEnv;var DDP=Package["ddp-client"].DDP;if(typeof Package==="undefined")Package={};(function(pkg,symbols){for(var s in symbols)s in pkg||(pkg[s]=symbols[s])})(Package.ddp={},{DDP:DDP})})();(function(){var Meteor=Package.meteor.Meteor;var global=Package.meteor.global;var meteorEnv=Package.meteor.meteorEnv;var _=Package.underscore._;var LocalCollection=Package.minimongo.LocalCollection;var Minimongo=Package.minimongo.Minimongo;var check=Package.check.check;var Match=Package.check.Match;var EJSON=Package.ejson.EJSON;var DDP=Package["ddp-client"].DDP;var meteorInstall=Package.modules.meteorInstall;var Buffer=Package.modules.Buffer;var process=Package.modules.process;var Symbol=Package["ecmascript-runtime"].Symbol;var Map=Package["ecmascript-runtime"].Map;var Set=Package["ecmascript-runtime"].Set;var meteorBabelHelpers=Package["babel-runtime"].meteorBabelHelpers;var Promise=Package.promise.Promise;var AllowDeny;var require=meteorInstall({node_modules:{meteor:{"allow-deny":{"allow-deny.js":function(){AllowDeny={CollectionPrototype:{}};var CollectionPrototype=AllowDeny.CollectionPrototype;CollectionPrototype.allow=function(options){addValidator(this,"allow",options)};CollectionPrototype.deny=function(options){addValidator(this,"deny",options)};CollectionPrototype._defineMutationMethods=function(options){var self=this;options=options||{};self._restricted=false;self._insecure=undefined;self._validators={insert:{allow:[],deny:[]},update:{allow:[],deny:[]},remove:{allow:[],deny:[]},upsert:{allow:[],deny:[]},fetch:[],fetchAllFields:false};if(!self._name)return;self._prefix="/"+self._name+"/";if(self._connection&&(self._connection===Meteor.server||Meteor.isClient)){(function(){var m={};_.each(["insert","update","remove"],function(method){var methodName=self._prefix+method;if(options.useExisting){var handlerPropName=Meteor.isClient?"_methodHandlers":"method_handlers";if(self._connection[handlerPropName]&&typeof self._connection[handlerPropName][methodName]==="function")return}m[methodName]=function(){check(arguments,[Match.Any]);var args=_.toArray(arguments);try{var generatedId=null;if(method==="insert"&&!_.has(args[0],"_id")){generatedId=self._makeNewID()}if(this.isSimulation){if(generatedId!==null)args[0]._id=generatedId;return self._collection[method].apply(self._collection,args)}if(method!=="insert")throwIfSelectorIsNotId(args[0],method);if(self._restricted){if(self._validators[method].allow.length===0){throw new Meteor.Error(403,"Access denied. No allow validators set on restricted "+"collection for method '"+method+"'.")}var validatedMethodName="_validated"+method.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+method.slice(1);args.unshift(this.userId);method==="insert"&&args.push(generatedId);return self[validatedMethodName].apply(self,args)}else if(self._isInsecure()){if(generatedId!==null)args[0]._id=generatedId;return self._collection[method].apply(self._collection,args)}else{throw new Meteor.Error(403,"Access denied")}}catch(e){if(e.name==="MongoError"||e.name==="MinimongoError"){throw new Meteor.Error(409,e.toString())}else{throw e}}}});self._connection.methods(m)})()}};CollectionPrototype._updateFetch=function(fields){var self=this;if(!self._validators.fetchAllFields){if(fields){self._validators.fetch=_.union(self._validators.fetch,fields)}else{self._validators.fetchAllFields=true;self._validators.fetch=null}}};CollectionPrototype._isInsecure=function(){var self=this;if(self._insecure===undefined)return!!Package.insecure;return self._insecure};CollectionPrototype._validatedInsert=function(userId,doc,generatedId){var self=this;if(_.any(self._validators.insert.deny,function(validator){return validator(userId,docToValidate(validator,doc,generatedId))})){throw new Meteor.Error(403,"Access denied")}if(_.all(self._validators.insert.allow,function(validator){return!validator(userId,docToValidate(validator,doc,generatedId))})){throw new Meteor.Error(403,"Access denied")}if(generatedId!==null)doc._id=generatedId;self._collection.insert.call(self._collection,doc)};CollectionPrototype._validatedUpdate=function(userId,selector,mutator,options){var self=this;check(mutator,Object);options=_.clone(options)||{};if(!LocalCollection._selectorIsIdPerhapsAsObject(selector))throw new Error("validated update should be of a single ID");if(options.upsert)throw new Meteor.Error(403,"Access denied. Upserts not "+"allowed in a restricted collection.");var noReplaceError="Access denied. In a restricted collection you can only"+" update documents, not replace them. Use a Mongo update operator, such "+"as '$set'.";var fields=[];if(_.isEmpty(mutator)){throw new Meteor.Error(403,noReplaceError)}_.each(mutator,function(params,op){if(op.charAt(0)!=="$"){throw new Meteor.Error(403,noReplaceError)}else if(!_.has(ALLOWED_UPDATE_OPERATIONS,op)){throw new Meteor.Error(403,"Access denied. Operator "+op+" not allowed in a restricted collection.")}else{_.each(_.keys(params),function(field){if(field.indexOf(".")!==-1)field=field.substring(0,field.indexOf("."));if(!_.contains(fields,field))fields.push(field)})}});var findOptions={transform:null};if(!self._validators.fetchAllFields){findOptions.fields={};_.each(self._validators.fetch,function(fieldName){findOptions.fields[fieldName]=1})}var doc=self._collection.findOne(selector,findOptions);if(!doc)return 0;if(_.any(self._validators.update.deny,function(validator){var factoriedDoc=transformDoc(validator,doc);return validator(userId,factoriedDoc,fields,mutator)})){throw new Meteor.Error(403,"Access denied")}if(_.all(self._validators.update.allow,function(validator){var factoriedDoc=transformDoc(validator,doc);return!validator(userId,factoriedDoc,fields,mutator)})){throw new Meteor.Error(403,"Access denied")}options._forbidReplace=true;return self._collection.update.call(self._collection,selector,mutator,options)};var ALLOWED_UPDATE_OPERATIONS={$inc:1,$set:1,$unset:1,$addToSet:1,$pop:1,$pullAll:1,$pull:1,$pushAll:1,$push:1,$bit:1};CollectionPrototype._validatedRemove=function(userId,selector){var self=this;var findOptions={transform:null};if(!self._validators.fetchAllFields){findOptions.fields={};_.each(self._validators.fetch,function(fieldName){findOptions.fields[fieldName]=1})}var doc=self._collection.findOne(selector,findOptions);if(!doc)return 0;if(_.any(self._validators.remove.deny,function(validator){return validator(userId,transformDoc(validator,doc))})){throw new Meteor.Error(403,"Access denied")}if(_.all(self._validators.remove.allow,function(validator){return!validator(userId,transformDoc(validator,doc))})){throw new Meteor.Error(403,"Access denied")}return self._collection.remove.call(self._collection,selector)};CollectionPrototype._callMutatorMethod=function(){function _callMutatorMethod(name,args,callback){if(Meteor.isClient&&!callback&&!alreadyInSimulation()){callback=function(){function callback(err){if(err)Meteor._debug(name+" failed: "+(err.reason||err.stack))}return callback}()}var firstArgIsSelector=name==="update"||name==="remove";if(firstArgIsSelector&&!alreadyInSimulation()){throwIfSelectorIsNotId(args[0],name)}var mutatorMethodName=this._prefix+name;return this._connection.apply(mutatorMethodName,args,{returnStubValue:true},callback)}return _callMutatorMethod}();function transformDoc(validator,doc){if(validator.transform)return validator.transform(doc);return doc}function docToValidate(validator,doc,generatedId){var ret=doc;if(validator.transform){ret=EJSON.clone(doc);if(generatedId!==null){ret._id=generatedId}ret=validator.transform(ret)}return ret}function addValidator(collection,allowOrDeny,options){var VALID_KEYS=["insert","update","remove","fetch","transform"];_.each(_.keys(options),function(key){if(!_.contains(VALID_KEYS,key))throw new Error(allowOrDeny+": Invalid key: "+key)});collection._restricted=true;_.each(["insert","update","remove"],function(name){if(options.hasOwnProperty(name)){if(!(options[name]instanceof Function)){throw new Error(allowOrDeny+": Value for `"+name+"` must be a function")}if(options.transform===undefined){options[name].transform=collection._transform}else{options[name].transform=LocalCollection.wrapTransform(options.transform)}collection._validators[name][allowOrDeny].push(options[name])}});if(options.update||options.remove||options.fetch){if(options.fetch&&!(options.fetch instanceof Array)){throw new Error(allowOrDeny+": Value for `fetch` must be an array")}collection._updateFetch(options.fetch)}}function throwIfSelectorIsNotId(selector,methodName){if(!LocalCollection._selectorIsIdPerhapsAsObject(selector)){throw new Meteor.Error(403,"Not permitted. Untrusted code may only "+methodName+" documents by ID.")}}function alreadyInSimulation(){var enclosing=DDP._CurrentInvocation.get();return enclosing&&enclosing.isSimulation}}}}}},{extensions:[".js",".json"]});require("./node_modules/meteor/allow-deny/allow-deny.js");if(typeof Package==="undefined")Package={};(function(pkg,symbols){for(var s in symbols)s in pkg||(pkg[s]=symbols[s])})(Package["allow-deny"]={},{AllowDeny:AllowDeny})})();(function(){var Meteor=Package.meteor.Meteor;var global=Package.meteor.global;var meteorEnv=Package.meteor.meteorEnv;var AllowDeny=Package["allow-deny"].AllowDeny;var Random=Package.random.Random;var EJSON=Package.ejson.EJSON;var _=Package.underscore._;var LocalCollection=Package.minimongo.LocalCollection;var Minimongo=Package.minimongo.Minimongo;var DDP=Package["ddp-client"].DDP;var Tracker=Package.tracker.Tracker;var Deps=Package.tracker.Deps;var DiffSequence=Package["diff-sequence"].DiffSequence;var MongoID=Package["mongo-id"].MongoID;var check=Package.check.check;var Match=Package.check.Match;var meteorInstall=Package.modules.meteorInstall;var Buffer=Package.modules.Buffer;var process=Package.modules.process;var Symbol=Package["ecmascript-runtime"].Symbol;var Map=Package["ecmascript-runtime"].Map;var Set=Package["ecmascript-runtime"].Set;var meteorBabelHelpers=Package["babel-runtime"].meteorBabelHelpers;var Promise=Package.promise.Promise;var LocalCollectionDriver,Mongo;var require=meteorInstall({node_modules:{meteor:{mongo:{"local_collection_driver.js":function(){LocalCollectionDriver=function LocalCollectionDriver(){var self=this;self.noConnCollections={}};var ensureCollection=function ensureCollection(name,collections){if(!(name in collections))collections[name]=new LocalCollection(name);return collections[name]};_.extend(LocalCollectionDriver.prototype,{open:function(){function open(name,conn){var self=this;if(!name)return new LocalCollection;if(!conn){return ensureCollection(name,self.noConnCollections)}if(!conn._mongo_livedata_collections)conn._mongo_livedata_collections={};return ensureCollection(name,conn._mongo_livedata_collections)}return open}()});LocalCollectionDriver=new LocalCollectionDriver},"collection.js":function(require,exports,module){Mongo={};Mongo.Collection=function(name,options){var self=this;if(!(self instanceof Mongo.Collection))throw new Error('use "new" to construct a Mongo.Collection');if(!name&&name!==null){Meteor._debug("Warning: creating anonymous collection. It will not be "+"saved or synchronized over the network. (Pass null for "+"the collection name to turn off this warning.)");name=null}if(name!==null&&typeof name!=="string"){throw new Error("First argument to new Mongo.Collection must be a string or null")}if(options&&options.methods){options={connection:options}}if(options&&options.manager&&!options.connection){options.connection=options.manager}options=_.extend({connection:undefined,idGeneration:"STRING",transform:null,_driver:undefined,_preventAutopublish:false},options);switch(options.idGeneration){case"MONGO":self._makeNewID=function(){var src=name?DDP.randomStream("/collection/"+name):Random.insecure;return new Mongo.ObjectID(src.hexString(24))};break;case"STRING":default:self._makeNewID=function(){var src=name?DDP.randomStream("/collection/"+name):Random.insecure;return src.id()};break}self._transform=LocalCollection.wrapTransform(options.transform);if(!name||options.connection===null)self._connection=null;else if(options.connection)self._connection=options.connection;else if(Meteor.isClient)self._connection=Meteor.connection;else self._connection=Meteor.server;if(!options._driver){if(name&&self._connection===Meteor.server&&typeof MongoInternals!=="undefined"&&MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver){options._driver=MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver()}else{options._driver=LocalCollectionDriver}}self._collection=options._driver.open(name,self._connection);self._name=name;self._driver=options._driver;if(self._connection&&self._connection.registerStore){var ok=self._connection.registerStore(name,{beginUpdate:function(){function beginUpdate(batchSize,reset){if(batchSize>1||reset)self._collection.pauseObservers();if(reset)self._collection.remove({})}return beginUpdate}(),update:function(){function update(msg){var mongoId=MongoID.idParse(msg.id);var doc=self._collection.findOne(mongoId);if(msg.msg==="replace"){var replace=msg.replace;if(!replace){if(doc)self._collection.remove(mongoId)}else if(!doc){self._collection.insert(replace)}else{self._collection.update(mongoId,replace)}return}else if(msg.msg==="added"){if(doc){throw new Error("Expected not to find a document already present for an add")}self._collection.insert(_.extend({_id:mongoId},msg.fields))}else if(msg.msg==="removed"){if(!doc)throw new Error("Expected to find a document already present for removed");self._collection.remove(mongoId)}else if(msg.msg==="changed"){if(!doc)throw new Error("Expected to find a document to change");if(!_.isEmpty(msg.fields)){var modifier={};_.each(msg.fields,function(value,key){if(value===undefined){if(!modifier.$unset)modifier.$unset={};modifier.$unset[key]=1}else{if(!modifier.$set)modifier.$set={};modifier.$set[key]=value}});self._collection.update(mongoId,modifier)}}else{throw new Error("I don't know how to deal with this message")}}return update}(),endUpdate:function(){function endUpdate(){self._collection.resumeObservers()}return endUpdate}(),saveOriginals:function(){function saveOriginals(){self._collection.saveOriginals()}return saveOriginals}(),retrieveOriginals:function(){function retrieveOriginals(){return self._collection.retrieveOriginals()}return retrieveOriginals}(),getDoc:function(){function getDoc(id){return self.findOne(id)}return getDoc}(),_getCollection:function(){function _getCollection(){return self}return _getCollection}()});if(!ok){var message='There is already a collection named "'+name+'"';if(options._suppressSameNameError===true){console.warn?console.warn(message):console.log(message)}else{throw new Error(message)}}}if(options.defineMutationMethods!==false){try{self._defineMutationMethods({useExisting:options._suppressSameNameError===true})}catch(error){if(error.message==="A method named '/"+name+"/insert' is already defined")throw new Error('There is already a collection named "'+name+'"');throw error}}if(Package.autopublish&&!options._preventAutopublish&&self._connection&&self._connection.publish){self._connection.publish(null,function(){return self.find()},{is_auto:true})}};_.extend(Mongo.Collection.prototype,{_getFindSelector:function(){function _getFindSelector(args){if(args.length==0)return{};else return args[0]}return _getFindSelector}(),_getFindOptions:function(){function _getFindOptions(args){var self=this;if(args.length<2){return{transform:self._transform}}else{check(args[1],Match.Optional(Match.ObjectIncluding({fields:Match.Optional(Match.OneOf(Object,undefined)),sort:Match.Optional(Match.OneOf(Object,Array,Function,undefined)),limit:Match.Optional(Match.OneOf(Number,undefined)),skip:Match.Optional(Match.OneOf(Number,undefined))})));return _.extend({transform:self._transform},args[1])}}return _getFindOptions}(),find:function(){function find(){var self=this;var argArray=_.toArray(arguments);return self._collection.find(self._getFindSelector(argArray),self._getFindOptions(argArray))}return find}(),findOne:function(){function findOne(){var self=this;var argArray=_.toArray(arguments);return self._collection.findOne(self._getFindSelector(argArray),self._getFindOptions(argArray))}return findOne}()});Mongo.Collection._publishCursor=function(cursor,sub,collection){var observeHandle=cursor.observeChanges({added:function(){function added(id,fields){sub.added(collection,id,fields)}return added}(),changed:function(){function changed(id,fields){sub.changed(collection,id,fields)}return changed}(),removed:function(){function removed(id){sub.removed(collection,id)}return removed}()});sub.onStop(function(){observeHandle.stop()});return observeHandle};Mongo.Collection._rewriteSelector=function(selector){if(LocalCollection._selectorIsId(selector))selector={_id:selector};if(_.isArray(selector)){throw new Error("Mongo selector can't be an array.")}if(!selector||"_id"in selector&&!selector._id)return{_id:Random.id()};var ret={};_.each(selector,function(value,key){if(value instanceof RegExp){ret[key]=convertRegexpToMongoSelector(value)}else if(value&&value.$regex instanceof RegExp){ret[key]=convertRegexpToMongoSelector(value.$regex);if(value.$options!==undefined)ret[key].$options=value.$options}else if(_.contains(["$or","$and","$nor"],key)){ret[key]=_.map(value,function(v){return Mongo.Collection._rewriteSelector(v)})}else{ret[key]=value}});return ret};function convertRegexpToMongoSelector(regexp){check(regexp,RegExp);var selector={$regex:regexp.source};var regexOptions="";if(regexp.ignoreCase)regexOptions+="i";if(regexp.multiline)regexOptions+="m";if(regexOptions)selector.$options=regexOptions;return selector}Mongo.Collection.prototype.insert=function(){function insert(doc,callback){if(!doc){throw new Error("insert requires an argument")}doc=_.extend({},doc);if("_id"in doc){if(!doc._id||!(typeof doc._id==="string"||doc._id instanceof Mongo.ObjectID)){throw new Error("Meteor requires document _id fields to be non-empty strings or ObjectIDs")}}else{var generateId=true;if(this._isRemoteCollection()){var enclosing=DDP._CurrentInvocation.get();if(!enclosing){generateId=false}}if(generateId){doc._id=this._makeNewID()}}var chooseReturnValueFromCollectionResult=function(){function chooseReturnValueFromCollectionResult(result){if(doc._id){return doc._id}doc._id=result;return result}return chooseReturnValueFromCollectionResult}();var wrappedCallback=wrapCallback(callback,chooseReturnValueFromCollectionResult);if(this._isRemoteCollection()){var result=this._callMutatorMethod("insert",[doc],wrappedCallback);return chooseReturnValueFromCollectionResult(result)}try{var _result=this._collection.insert(doc,wrappedCallback);return chooseReturnValueFromCollectionResult(_result)}catch(e){if(callback){callback(e);return null}throw e}}return insert}();Mongo.Collection.prototype.update=function(){function update(selector,modifier){for(var _len=arguments.length,optionsAndCallback=Array(_len>2?_len-2:0),_key=2;_key<_len;_key++){optionsAndCallback[_key-2]=arguments[_key]}var callback=popCallbackFromArgs(optionsAndCallback);selector=Mongo.Collection._rewriteSelector(selector);var options=_.clone(optionsAndCallback[0])||{};if(options&&options.upsert){if(options.insertedId){if(!(typeof options.insertedId==="string"||options.insertedId instanceof Mongo.ObjectID))throw new Error("insertedId must be string or ObjectID")}else if(!selector._id){options.insertedId=this._makeNewID()}}var wrappedCallback=wrapCallback(callback);if(this._isRemoteCollection()){var args=[selector,modifier,options];return this._callMutatorMethod("update",args,wrappedCallback)}try{return this._collection.update(selector,modifier,options,wrappedCallback)}catch(e){if(callback){callback(e);return null}throw e}}return update}();Mongo.Collection.prototype.remove=function(){function remove(selector,callback){selector=Mongo.Collection._rewriteSelector(selector);var wrappedCallback=wrapCallback(callback);if(this._isRemoteCollection()){return this._callMutatorMethod("remove",[selector],wrappedCallback)}try{return this._collection.remove(selector,wrappedCallback)}catch(e){if(callback){callback(e);return null}throw e}}return remove}();Mongo.Collection.prototype._isRemoteCollection=function(){function _isRemoteCollection(){return this._connection&&this._connection!==Meteor.server}return _isRemoteCollection}();function wrapCallback(callback,convertResult){if(!callback){return}convertResult=convertResult||_.identity;return function(error,result){callback(error,!error&&convertResult(result))}}Mongo.Collection.prototype.upsert=function(){function upsert(selector,modifier,options,callback){if(!callback&&typeof options==="function"){callback=options;options={}}var updateOptions=_.extend({},options,{_returnObject:true,upsert:true});return this.update(selector,modifier,updateOptions,callback)}return upsert}();Mongo.Collection.prototype._ensureIndex=function(index,options){var self=this;if(!self._collection._ensureIndex)throw new Error("Can only call _ensureIndex on server collections");self._collection._ensureIndex(index,options)};Mongo.Collection.prototype._dropIndex=function(index){var self=this;if(!self._collection._dropIndex)throw new Error("Can only call _dropIndex on server collections");self._collection._dropIndex(index)};Mongo.Collection.prototype._dropCollection=function(){var self=this;if(!self._collection.dropCollection)throw new Error("Can only call _dropCollection on server collections");self._collection.dropCollection()};Mongo.Collection.prototype._createCappedCollection=function(byteSize,maxDocuments){var self=this;if(!self._collection._createCappedCollection)throw new Error("Can only call _createCappedCollection on server collections");self._collection._createCappedCollection(byteSize,maxDocuments)};Mongo.Collection.prototype.rawCollection=function(){var self=this;if(!self._collection.rawCollection){throw new Error("Can only call rawCollection on server collections")}return self._collection.rawCollection()};Mongo.Collection.prototype.rawDatabase=function(){var self=this;if(!(self._driver.mongo&&self._driver.mongo.db)){throw new Error("Can only call rawDatabase on server collections")}return self._driver.mongo.db};Mongo.ObjectID=MongoID.ObjectID;Mongo.Cursor=LocalCollection.Cursor;Mongo.Collection.Cursor=Mongo.Cursor;Mongo.Collection.ObjectID=Mongo.ObjectID;Meteor.Collection=Mongo.Collection;_.extend(Meteor.Collection.prototype,AllowDeny.CollectionPrototype);function popCallbackFromArgs(args){if(args.length&&(args[args.length-1]===undefined||args[args.length-1]instanceof Function)){return args.pop()}}}}}}},{extensions:[".js",".json"]});require("./node_modules/meteor/mongo/local_collection_driver.js");require("./node_modules/meteor/mongo/collection.js");if(typeof Package==="undefined")Package={};(function(pkg,symbols){for(var s in symbols)s in pkg||(pkg[s]=symbols[s])})(Package.mongo={},{Mongo:Mongo})})();Meteor=Package.meteor.Meteor;global=Package.meteor.global;meteorEnv=Package.meteor.meteorEnv;_=Package.underscore._;DDP=Package["ddp-client"].DDP;Mongo=Package.mongo.Mongo;Tracker=Package.tracker.Tracker;Deps=Package.tracker.Deps;
```

Comment: By "freezes" you mean that you never get `setLocalNessage done`, but not an exception either?

Comment: That's correct, no errors, but line after the insert is not reached

Comment: Is it because I am calling the function from within a `subscribe`?

Comment: I don't know, what does `insert` do? Does is synchronously publish notifications?

Comment: It's part of the Meteor api. `insert(doc: T, callback?: Function): string;`  I will try debug it.

Comment: Very strange, when I debug it, and step through the code it works. So it may be a timing issue?

Comment: `insert` function returns a `string`. `(method) Mongo.Collection<Message>.insert(doc: Message, callback?: Function): string`

Comment: Ok, so I am confussed. You mentioned you are doing the insert inside of a subscription? Where is the subscription? It looks like you are creating a local-only collection (indicated by the null name), which means there is no synchronization on this collection at all.

Comment: It is only a local collection with no sync to the server. However, I do populate it with data from the server initially, then delete the messages from the server (not implemented yet). That's the reason it's in the subscription.