# JavaScript 'this' scope in window.setInterval

Tags: javascript, oop, this, setinterval

I'm new to Javascript, so could anyone tell me why the value of 'this' changes depending on which function I'm calling it from. Am I not calling the `addquote` as a method (#3 from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832062/the-scope-of-this)? I mostly wrote this as an OOP exercise, so if anyone could point me in the way of good documentation that would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

```
function QuoteBox(text, author){
    this.quote = new Quote(text, author);
    this.element = document.getElementById("quotebox");
}


QuoteBox.prototype.removequote = function(c){
        // do some animation here and maybe move the removal to a callback
    this.element.children[0].innerHTML = "";
    this.element.children[1].innerHTML = "";
    c();
}

QuoteBox.prototype.addquote = function(){
    console.log(this); // outputs the window ?!
    this.element.children[0].innerHTML =quote.text;
    this.element.children[1].innerHTML =quote.author;
}

QuoteBox.prototype.refresh = function(){
    console.log(this); // outputs the quotebox object
    this.quote.generate();
    this.removequote(this.addquote);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    quotebox = new QuoteBox("Quote", "Author");
    window.setInterval(function(){
        quotebox.refresh();
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Take a look at this question and its answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal

Comment: Thanks for the references! Let me know if there's any point of stackoverflow etiquette I'm not following, I'm new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the function like this:

```
this.removequote(this.addquote);
```

You're passing in ***the reference*** to the `addquote` into `removequote`, so your `c` holds a reference to the `addquote` method but ***not the context***. When you call `c()`, this method will be invoked in global context. You can bind context to the method using [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). Like this:

```
this.removequote(this.addquote.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you call `c()` in `removequote` function without specifying target object for this call. So, it shoud be
`c.call(this)`

Good article about this topic - http://unschooled.org/2012/03/understanding-javascript-this/