# Alternative for Jquery.apply

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I was learning j-query with some video courses, in that i found they were using $.apply , looks latest version of j-query had abandoned it. Is there any alternative for it in the latest version 2.1.0 ?

Comment: `$.apply` is not provided by jQuery. It's a property of all functions.

Comment: See documentation for `.apply()` on all functions here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: As you've heard that the apply function isn't part of jQuery, This seems like a case of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe if you'd provide where you need to use it in your code, you could get a specific alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[What's the .apply jQuery function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796788/whats-the-apply-jquery-function)

It's not a jQuery function. Any function in javascript has an `.apply()` method. And the `$ or jQuery` object is no different.

It's used to change the scope (http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Context.2C_Call_and_Apply), but I don't see any reason to use it.

Depending on your code, you might be looking for the `$.proxy()`..?